# Type '(key: String, value: Any)' has no subscript members

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I loop through an array of dictionary with this code.

```
if let users = object["usersList"] as? [Any] {
    for user in users as! [String : Any] {
        print(user["id"])
    }
}
```

Each dictionary has an `id` attribute. When I want to access it with `user["id"]`, I get the error:

> Type '(key: String, value: Any)' has no subscript members

Comment: Why don't you do the `as! [String : Any]` in the `if-let` statement (first line)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are casting the array to a dictionary which cannot work.

The easiest solution is to (optional down)cast `users` to specific `[[String : Any]]`

```
if let users = object["usersList"] as? [[String : Any]] {
    for user in users {
        print(user["id"])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't force-unwrap with `as!`, instead use the conditional unwrapping as you did before :

```
if let users = object["usersList"] as? [Any] {
    for user in users
        if let user = user as? [String : Any] {
            if let userId = user["id"] {
                print(userId)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That way you're sure you won't come across a crash. You can also use an if-guard statement if you don't like the whole nested thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
if let users = object["usersList"] as? [Any]{
   for user in users as! [[String : Any]]{
      print(user["id"])
   }
}
```